# How do you add page specific logic to jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I've read [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) that you cannot use `$(document).ready()` on each jqMobile page. Instead the recommend using `pageInit()` and `pageCreate()`. This is all well and good, but I'm not quite sure how to go about implementing it.

Let's say I have a list of URLs that all lead to separate reports. Each report is going to have various things that need to occur when the page loads.

Do I have to put all the page logic into the main page?

This is a generic question, but I will give a specific example of what I'm trying to do.

An MVC3 `Layout` page has my head element with all script references.

Then I have my index page:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">

<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="a">Category 1</li>
            <li><a href="someUrl" data-transition="slideup">Link 1</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then a separate landing page for my report:

```
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">  
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Report 1</h1>
    <a id="btnOpts" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Options</a>
</div>
```

Then I have one last page for my options dialog:

```
<div id="dlgOpts" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="content">

    <h2>Please select the report options:</h2>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="startDate" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox"}' />
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="endDate">End Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="endDate" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}' />
    </div>

    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-icon="back" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Cancel</a></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="#" data-icon="check" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Ok</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to load the report from the list, and when the report loads, show the options dialog. If I put it inline within the page, it always loops back to the options because it fires when the dialog closes (I guess that's a full reload of the page below it?).

So in short: How do I load the dialog when my report page loads, and then do *something*  when the options dialog closes?

Comment: Place all javascript in your index or what ever page you load first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to include my site-wide JavaScript at the end of every HTML document, so if the user refreshed the page on any page in the site, that JavaScript will load and be available for the site. My structure looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>My Fancy Mobile Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="library/css/default.css">

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <!-- Content Here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="library/js/default.js"></script></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that jQuery Mobile is being included in the `<head>` of the document and my custom JavaScript (`default.js`) is included at the bottom of the page to not block page rendering.

Now to use the jQuery Mobile version of `$(document).ready();`:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pagecreate', function () {
    //code here will run each time a page is enhanced by jQuery Mobile, which will be once per page
});

$('[data-role="page"]').live('pageshow', function () {
    //code here will run each time a page is navigated to, which can be many times if the user navigates away and back
});

//you can also bind to specific pages
$('#home').live('pageshow', function () {
    //code here will run each time the `#home` page is shown
});

//you can bind to any selector that selects the `data-role="page"` elements
$('.page_element_class').live('pageshow', function () {
    //code here will run each time any page with the `.page_element_class` class is shown
});
```

Also be careful of using IDs as they have to be unique site-wide, if two pages have an element with the same ID it will cause problems as many pages will be in the DOM at once.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

"it always loops back to the options because it fires when the dialog closes (I guess that's a full reload of the page below it?)."

I think it's because you are missing the HREF property on your A tag - what's the name of the dialog you are trying to open?

```
<a id="btnOpts" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Options</a>
```

That might be the reason why the whole page refreshes instead of just letting JQM load that dialog for you.
Once this works, you can use the suggestion provided by @Jasper, i.e.

```
$("#dialogname").live("pagebeforeshow", function(e, data){
  // here you prepare your dialog contents
});

$("#dialogname").live("pagebeforehide", function(e, data){
 // here you finalize before your dialog disappears
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for addressing that specific part, I will try adding that and seeing what happens.